# Adding a productAttribute handler in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, di

I'd like my Magento 2.4 module to be able to modify the output of one of the product attributes programatically. I see that the ability to create a handler for this purpose was [added in Magento 2.3.4](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24405), using di.xml, however, I'm unclear on how to actually set this up. What do I need to do to make a simple productAttribute handler that modifies the output for one of my attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A developer posted the answer here:](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/8587)

etc/di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output">
<arguments>
    <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="productattribute" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="myHandler" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Handler\Output</item>
        </item>
        <item name="categoryattribute" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="myHandler" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Handler\Output</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

Vendor\Module\Model\Handler\Output.php:

```
namespace  Vendor\Module\Model\Handler;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output as HelperOutput;

class Output
{
    public function productAttribute(HelperOutput $output, string $attributeHtml, array $params): string
    {
        // $params: ['product' => $product, 'attribute' => $attributeName]
        // todo your output handler
        return $attributeHtml;
    }

    public function categoryAttribute(HelperOutput $output, string $attributeHtml, array $params): string
    {
        // $params: ['category' => $category, 'attribute' => $attributeName]
        // todo your output handler
        return $attributeHtml;
    }
}
```